# Missing views generator for Rails; resulting in error 'Could not find generator...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to run the following command after installing the Devise gem:

```
Gunface:/ Jacob$ cd ~/12-in-12/Forum 
Gunface:Forum Jacob$ rails g devise:views
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find generator 'devise:views'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'scss:assets' or 'js:assets'
```

I've run the helper, and the views generator is in fact missing:

```
Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task
```

I have definitely followed the instructions that appear after installing Devise.

So, is there a way to create a views generator in a Rails app? I have no idea how to fix this, and I haven't found a similar question that helped resolve this problem.

Comment: How did  you add devise to your Gemfile? In a group?

Comment: I figured it out. I have multiple versions of the same type of Rails app, and I installed the Devise gem for all except one. I'm sorry, this is a rookie mistake by a rookie Rails user! The command 'rails g devise:views' worked after I saved the gem in the Gem file and ran 'bundle install'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Devise gem to Gemfile, then specify the ruby version in line 2 with
    ruby '2.2.2'

Save the Gemfile

Run
    $ bundle install

Run
    $ rails g devise:views

Comment: Using TextWrangler, btw.